# Join Lines in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

According to the [release notes of Eclipse 3.3](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news-all.html) you can now join lines together with CRTL-ALT-J. This doesn't work for me running Eclipse 3.5 on a Mac. Does it work for anyone else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For mac, there is no key binding assigned by default (I'm using Eclipse 3.5 for Mac). You can assign your own bind if you want eg: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

1. Go to preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Navigation to "General > Keys"
3. In the filter bar, search for "join". Click on the command "Join Lines"
4. Click in the "Binding" box and then type the keys you wish to bind to this action.

Comment: Done that but it doesn't do anything hence the question. Cheers.

Comment: On the "When" drop down, try selecting "Editing Java Source". Now it works for me.

Comment: Got it. Noticed that even though the Keys Prerferences panel did not have any binding conflicts it was showing "Reverse Incremental Find" in the status bar at the bottom when trying to use my key binding. Changed to something more obscure and it's fine. Also set my "When" to "In Dialogs and Windows" so it works in Java and XHTML. Thanks.

Comment: @ewalk When "Editing Text" is more general so it works in all types of files.